# Fortran variable has different value

Tags: debugging, gdb, fortran, fortran77

I have a FORTRAN program, where I assign PI=3.14159265

when I run the program, my numbers could out slightly off.
So i recompiled with debug flags set, and started stepping through with gdb.
A few lines in, I notice PI is not what i set it to?

(gdb) s

57         PI=3.14159265

(gdb) s

58         TWOPI= 2* PI

(gdb) print pi

$1 = 3.1415927410125732

What is going on here? I would understand if PI was a system value, but if it is, why is the value wrong?? how should i fix this?

Comment: Obligatory [What every computer scientist should know about floating point arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Goldberg's paper, referenced by @KyleKanos, has acquired the status (here on SO) of holy writ.  Unfortunately for the disciple it is, like much scripture, a tough read.  I think a much better reference for the beginner is the Wikipedia article (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point).  Then, if you want to know more and more deeply, tackle Goldberg's paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is printing the best binary approximation to the value of pi you entered; I get exactly the same answer in C using a float. You can get more accuracy by going to double precision, but this is as close as you can get to your value using binary with 32 bits and the usual representation of floating point numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a fortan expert by any means, though F77 was the last version that I used.  That does look about correct for the estimation which is single precision floating point representation.  The short answer is that all numbers are represented in base 2.  Single precision floating point representation for 3.14159265 ends up being 3.14159274...  The [wikipedia article for Single-Precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision) is surprisingly good for the subject.  If you are interested, you should read Goldberg's [*"What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"*](http://www.validlab.com/goldberg/paper.pdf).

Your example is actually represented as something pretty close to:

```
(1 + (4788187 * (2 ^ -23))) * 2
```

Comment: I agree with your suggestions for further reading, in particular placing Goldberg's paper second on the list rather than first.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the rounding done for the representation as floating-point number.

You can define `pi` as parameter using

```
REAL, PARAMETER :: pi = 4. * ATAN(1.)  ! set pi = 3.14...
```

to get a good representation of `pi` without worrying about the decimal to type in. This approach allows to increase the precession by changing the kind values of `pi`, `4.` and `1.`. It might help to get expected results from trigonometric functions, e.g. `SIN(pi)`.

Comment: I have been told that `pi=acos(-1.0)` is 2 bits more accurate than using atan.

Comment: @KyleKanos I could not prove this using gfortran 4.8.2.

Comment: I was told this by a CS friend of mine, I have yet to test it myself.

Comment: In single precision 3.14159250 < pi < 3.14159274  (13176794.6/2^22), the larger value seems obviously closer. ie what joh keyed in is as good as any other approach.